# Key binding in VIM

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

How can I bind key and its options?

Example:
`dw` - deletes one word. `d3w` - deletes three words. I want to use `eo` to delete one word, and `e3o` to delete three words. I can bind `d` to `e`, but the problem is I cannot bind option/movement key (e.g `w` to `o` in this example).

I tried:

```
nnoremap e d|xnoremap e d
nnoremap eo dw|xnoremap eo dw
```

or

```
nnoremap o w|xnoremap o w
nnoremap e d|xnoremap e d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is "operator pending mappings". You can remap the movement keys to specific actions.

In your case what you need to do is remap d to e

```
:nnoremap e d
```

And then remap the "w" movement to "o"

```
:onoremap o w
```

With this, both eo and e3o work.

Check this guide for a detailed description https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html

BTW: not sure if it's the best practice to remap VIM keybindings for basic actions such as deleting/inserting etc. as it can possibly mess up other bindings - unless some very specific usecase, maybe consider learning the default ones.